# The non-solvable Frobenuis groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-solvable Frobenius group with kernel K and complement $H$.
I know that $H$ has a normal subgroup $S$ of index at most $2$ such that $S\cong SL_2(5)\times Z$, where $2.3.5\nmid |Z|$·

If $|H/S|=2$, then $SL_2(5)\cong S/Z<H/Z$ and $H/Z$ is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $GL_2(5)$ of index $(q-1)/2$. Also, it is known that a Sylow $2$-subgroup of  $H/Z$ is a generalized quaternion group.

I try to find such subgroup of $GL_2(5)$, but I cannot find. My problem is that I see that $diag(1,-1)$ belongs to $H/Z$ always.  So its Sylow $2$-subgroup is not a generalized quaternion group. Am I rigth?

Comment: Why is it a subgroup of $GL_2(5)$?